# BiqQuery not taking month into consideration when sorting based on date

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the below query to app uninstalls per day and sort them based on date but the resulting sorted data is not getting sorted based on month only date is taken into consideration.
Query used:

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%d-%m-%Y', PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) AS dates,
COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS Unistalls
FROM `applied-buckeye-626.analytics_153768669.events_*` 
WHERE event_name='app_remove'
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > '20210828'
GROUP BY dates
ORDER BY dates DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "dates": "31-08-2021",
    "Unistalls": "5"
  },
  {
    "dates": "30-08-2021",
    "Unistalls": "7"
  },
  {
    "dates": "29-08-2021",
    "Unistalls": "6"
  },
  {
    "dates": "07-09-2021",
    "Unistalls": "3"
  },
  {
    "dates": "06-09-2021",
    "Unistalls": "5"
  },
  {
    "dates": "05-09-2021",
    "Unistalls": "4"
  },
  {
    "dates": "04-09-2021",
    "Unistalls": "7"
  },
  {
    "dates": "03-09-2021",
    "Unistalls": "3"
  },
  {
    "dates": "02-09-2021",
    "Unistalls": "2"
  },
  {
    "dates": "01-09-2021",
    "Unistalls": "4"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting by a string!  Not a date.  You can fix this just by using an aggregation function instead:

```
ORDER BY MIN(event_date) DESC
```

Or leave the date in YYYY-MM-DD format.  That format has many advantages, including sorting correctly.